# MySQL query to get data between muliple dates in a pandas df

Tags: python, sql, pandas, merge

I have being trying for a way to create a **MySQL query** that I would be able to run in Python and is able to get all the daily data from a BigQuery between two dates in a **Pandas DF**, the thing is every row has ***different days*** and ***IDs*** and I was not able to make it work in a single Query, the tables would be something like this:

```
**Pandas DF:**
| ID | Start_Date | End_Date   |
|----|------------|------------|
| A  | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-01 |
| B  | 2020-06-01 | 2021-06-01 |
| C  | 2021-06-01 | 2021-12-01 |

**Google Cloud Big Query**
| ID  |     Day    | V1  | V2  | V3  |
|-----|------------|-----|-----|-----|
| A   | 2020-01-01 | X   | 1   | 333 |
| A   | 2020-01-02 | Y   | 2   | 666 |
| A   | 2020-01-03 | Z   | 3   | 999 |
| B   | 2020-01-01 | A   | 10  | 0   |
| ... | ...        | ... | ... | ... |

**Desired Merged Table:**
| ID  | Start_Date | End_Date   | V1  | V2  | V3   |
|-----|------------|------------|-----|-----|------|
| A   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | X   | 1   | 333  |
| A   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | Y   | 2   | 666  |
| A   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | Z   | 3   | 999  |
| B   | 2021-06-01 | 2021-12-01 | h   | 20  | 1000 |
| ... | ...        |    ...     | ... | ... | ...  |
```

I have being using pandas.read_gbq to read the SQL query request, but right now I have executed a request for each id, making the hole process very slow and having multiple requests on the server side of things.
I have being using **something** like this inside a loop to get the different rows:

````py
 row_zero = pandasDF.iloc[0]
 start_date = row_zero.Start_Date
 end_date = row_zero.End_Date
 row = row_zero.ID

 query = """
 SELECT ID,V1,V2,V3 FROM <table>
 WHERE ID = '%s' AND Day BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
 """, % (row,start_date,end_date)

 query_result = pd.read_gbq(query)

 merged_data = pandasDF.merge(query_results, on='id', how='left')

 ```
````

Comment: are you using `mysql` or `sql-server` ?

Comment: well this is closed now - but this is how I would have done it (if you're using SQL Serer) write a your dataframe to SQL, write query and push that out to pandas solution here https://gist.github.com/umarhussain88/e9a2143ae2bd86a7628ca95e2029a149